# Linux - How to find a file with a keyword on a Windows network share

Tags: linux, smb

I'd like to know how i can find a file from Linux cli with a keyword on a Windows network share.

I've searched for find, but there's no network command.
I've searched for smbtree, but I doubt if you can search recursively.

Second question: would you be able to pipe the find command in smbtree recursively to all shares?

Love to hear your responses.

Kind regards,
Martijn

Comment: Just to clarify, you are on a linux machine and have windows a SMB share mounted somewhere in the file system, say under `/mntsmb` or a similar mount point?